# How do you read Twitter in order?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to catch up on old unread tweets, but when I query Twitter using the [Advance search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) screen with from date A to date B the tweets come back not in order.  The order is not random yet not chronological.  All I want to do is read tweets in order.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The order seems to be based on some sort of algorithm. If you perform the same search multiple times, the results will be the same, in the same order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can see tweets in order in **Latest** section. When you do a search, by default it shows search result in *Top* section. But if you click on Latest, you will see the tweets in an order from date B to date A.

Below is a screenshot of the sections when we search for anything:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks!